# AWS s3 javascript sdk: file key encodes spaces as %20 any ways to fix this using the endpoint params?

Tags: javascript, express, file, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have a form where a user can upload any file with any name. Later, I need to display this name as a download link. I've been stuck on the case where the file name includes characters like 'space'. AWS replaces space to "%20" which is bad UX.

See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/object-keys.html

I upload with the following params `s3.upload(uploadParams, function(err, data) {`

```
  const uploadParams = {
    Bucket: req.params.bucketname,
    Key: req.headers.filepath,
    Body: ""
  };
```

and download with the following params `s3.getObject(bucketParams, function(err, data) {`

```
  const bucketParams = {
    Bucket: req.params.bucketname,
    Key: req.headers.filepath,
  };
```

I am new to AWS and I am not sure the best way to approach this. I've tried using `Content-Disposition` but it didn't seem to do anything.

My next option would be store the filename in my db along with the fileURL so when I get the fileBody I would display it using the filename I previously stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a built-in javascript function `decodeURIComponent(string)`. It converts all `%xx` encodings to the corresponding characters in utf-8.